# I wanted to perform UPDATE on some fields in a table using SELECT

Tags: mysql

// this is the whole query im trying to compile

//down below is the code with errors. I'm unable to figure it out.

//Query Begins

//Error: Begins at "UPDATE d FROM....", is this syntax correct?

```
UPDATE d FROM Deployment d INNER JOIN Employment e ON d.employment_id = e.employment_id where e.consultant_id=14
   SET d.date_end = '2012-10-17',
       d.updated_by = 4,
       d.updated_date = SYSDATE()
 WHERE e.consultant_id = 14
   AND date_end IS NULL;
```

//Code ends here

Comment: The query "UPDATE Employment SET date_end = '2012-10-17', updated_by = 4, updated_date = SYSDATE() WHERE consultant_id = 14 AND date_end is null" doesn't work ? Which error is giving ?

Comment: please, edit your post and use code formatting controls in order to make possible to understand your code.

Comment: Error code:1064
Error message:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Deployment d INNER JOIN Employment e ON d.employment_id = e.employment_id w' at line 2 0.000 sec

Comment: Fixed this issue:
UPDATE Deployment d INNER JOIN Employment e ON d.employment_id = e.employment_id
    SET d.date_end = p_date_end,
     d.updated_by = p_loggedin_user_id,
     d.updated_date = SYSDATE()
  WHERE e.consultant_id = p_consultant_id
    AND d.date_end IS NULL;

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Deployment d 
INNER JOIN Employment e ON d.employment_id = e.employment_id SET d.date_end = p_date_e`nd, 
d.updated_by = p_loggedin_user_id, d.updated_date = SYSDATE() 
WHERE e.consultant_id = p_consultant_id
AND d.date_end IS NULL;
```